# 'error: ‘CKM_AES_CTR’ undeclared' while compiling libreswan-3.15

Tags: linux, pkcs#11, ipsec, l2tp

I am getting compilation error while compiling libreswan-3.15 source code.

make[3]: Entering directory `/root/libreswan-3.15/OBJ.linux.i386/programs/pluto'
cc   -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-all -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIE -DPIE -DFORCE_PR_ASSERT -DDNSSEC -DFIPS_CHECK -DFIPSPRODUCTCHECK=\"/etc/system-fips\" -DKLIPS -DLIBCURL -DUSE_LINUX_AUDIT -DUSE_MD5 -DHAVE_NM -DUSE_SHA2 -DUSE_SHA1 -DFIPSPRODUCTCHECK=\"/etc/system-fips\" -DIPSEC_CONF=\"/etc/ipsec.conf\" -DIPSEC_CONFDDIR=\"/etc/ipsec.d\" -DIPSEC_NSSDIR=\"/etc/ipsec.d\" -DIPSEC_CONFDIR=\"/etc\" -DIPSEC_EXECDIR=\"/usr/local/libexec/ipsec\" -DIPSEC_SBINDIR=\"/usr/local/sbin\" -DIPSEC_VARDIR=\"/var\" -DPOLICYGROUPSDIR=\"/etc/ipsec.d/policies\" -DSHARED_SECRETS_FILE=\"/etc/ipsec.secrets\" -DGCC_LINT -DALLOW_MICROSOFT_BAD_PROPOSAL  -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wundef -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -I/root/libreswan-3.15/ports/linux/include -I/root/libreswan-3.15/ports/linux/include -I/root/libreswan-3.15/ports/linux/include -I/root/libreswan-3.15/ports/linux/include  -I/root/libreswan-3.15/programs/pluto/linux26 -I/root/libreswan-3.15/include -I/root/libreswan-3.15/lib/libcrypto -I/root/libreswan-3.15/linux/include   -DUSE_KEYRR   -DNETKEY_SUPPORT -DKERNEL26_HAS_KAME_DUPLICATES -DPFKEY  -DUSE_TWOFISH -DUSE_SERPENT -DKLIPS -DPFKEY    -DUSE_AES -DUSE_3DES -DUSE_SHA2 -DUSE_SHA1 -DUSE_MD5 -DUSE_CAMELLIA   -DXAUTH_HAVE_PAM -DLIBCURL    -DFIPS_CHECK -DHAVE_LIBCAP_NG -DHAVE_NM -I/usr/include/nss3 -I/usr/include/nspr4     \
                -MMD -MF ./ctr_test_vectors.d \
                -o ./ctr_test_vectors.o \
                -c /root/libreswan-3.15/programs/pluto/ctr_test_vectors.c
/root/libreswan-3.15/programs/pluto/ctr_test_vectors.c: In function ‘test_aes_ctr’:
/root/libreswan-3.15/programs/pluto/ctr_test_vectors.c:243: error: ‘CKM_AES_CTR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/libreswan-3.15/programs/pluto/ctr_test_vectors.c:243: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/root/libreswan-3.15/programs/pluto/ctr_test_vectors.c:243: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[3]: *** [ctr_test_vectors.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory`/root/libreswan-3.15/OBJ.linux.i386/programs/pluto'
make[2]: *** [local-base] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/libreswan-3.15/programs/pluto'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory`/root/libreswan-3.15/programs'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Tried searching on internet but did not find the solution. Please provide some pointers so that I can fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

On my system the `CKM_AES_CTR` mechanism is declared in file `/usr/include/nss/pkcs11t.h` (which is included in the affected source file via `pk11pub.h`).

Check yours file `/usr/include/nss3/pkcs11t.h` (as your libnss might be outdated).

(I was unable to find which libnss version is required to build libreswan in their documentation)